# Postgres connection not possible

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, psycopg2

i have a problem connecting to my postgres. It is running in my Docker properly but i am not able to connect via python to that container. Additionally i get no error message. "e" is empty. Any idea why it doesnt work? The container is running locally on my machine.

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host="localhost",
        database="my_database",
        user="postgres",
        password="postgres"
    )
    print("Verbindung zur PostgreSQL-Datenbank erfolgreich hergestellt.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception")
    print(e)
    conn = None
```

YML:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: my_postgres_container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: my_database
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you program doesn't run in the same container, you have to use the container name for the connection:

```
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host="my_postgres_container",
        database="my_database",
        user="postgres",
        password="postgres"
    )
    print("Verbindung zur PostgreSQL-Datenbank erfolgreich hergestellt.")
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception")
    print(e)
    conn = None
```

Comment: could not translate host name "my_postgres_container" to address: host is unknown

Any idea? At least we get an error :D

Comment: Can you check that the container is running and you do not have a typo in the name?

Comment: Container is running, Error is still exisiting: 

"CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
463b5b6fffd9   postgres   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago   Up 48 minutes   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   my_postgres_container"

Answer (score 0):

I tried a different Port and suddenly it was working ...